# I am not getting Abandoned cart emails on mailchimp (magento 2)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.7

I am not getting Abandoned cart emails. 
Magento 2.1.8
Mailchimp 1.0.26

As list was not syncing on both sides so I manually ran cron job for it. Now list is sync but not getting any abandoned cart email.

**Account info**

```
Username: XXXXX
Total Subscribers: 32892
Ecommerce Data uploaded to MailChimp
Total Customers: 142
Total Products: 28
Total Orders: 7
Total Carts: 45
Account Synced since: 2018-03-14
```

And on magento side in Reports- > abandoned cart all user how abandoned cart are adding perfectly. So I think I am not getting webhook from magento to mailchimp ? or something like this ?

Answer (score 1):

Create one rule in Marketing > Email Reminders

Add your criteria and condition like this

> Shopping cart is not empty and abandoned for  1  days and ALL  of these conditions match:

Clear cache. It should work.

Comment: I want to get  abandoned  cart emails by mailchimp. its way to do it using magento I think ?